# Equidistant Date Axis on Non equidistant time points

Tags: matlab

So my x axis is based on time ticks which are not evenly spaced, some points happen within 2-4 seconds of each other while others can take an hour.

When using datetick it seems like the points are shifted such that those which happen within a short interval are compressed while the others are spaced out.  Is there anyway to allow the x axis to be evenly space and still be properly labelled through time?  What I don't want is for Matlab to be spacing my data points differently.

Comment: Can't you just plot against the indices of timestamps instead of their value? If `x` contains the times, instead of plotting over `x` you can plot over `1:numel(x)`

Comment: @MohsenNosratinia If I do that than how do I know what time what happened?

Comment: I can't reproduce this...can you provide some example data?

Comment: Are you *sure* they are compressed, and it's not just a scaling problem? I.e., I can still zoom in to the closely spaced points and see they are different

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis This is definitely a scaling problem if I zoom in the data is there, but "visually" it is spaced out differently in the plot in some areas vs others.  I'd like everything to be scaled evenly regardless of time.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis What is the easiest way to post sample data? Unfortunately the source itself is coming from a database i.e can't just reproduce with some commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot ask `datetick` to rearrange the data points on `x`-axis. You have to plot it evenly before that. Instead of using timestamps, use their indices and then ask `datestr` to label them. See the example below

```
timeStamps = {'00:00:01' '00:00:04' '01:05:09' '02:06:53' '05:08:09'};
xData = datenum(timeStamps);

yData = (1:numel(xData)).^2;

subplot(211)
plot(xData, yData)
set(gca, 'XTick', xData)
datetick('x', 'HH:MM:SS', 'keepticks')

subplot(212)
plot(1:numel(xData), yData)
set(gca, 'XTick', 1:numel(xData))
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', datestr(xData, 'HH:MM:SS'));
```

And the result

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice solution - it spaces the points evenly, and labels each point with the corresponding date. You might want to update your solution to show how to give date & time (or just time) in the label, since some of the points are "seconds apart". Also - if there are more than a dozen points, labels are going to overlap: can you show how to align them vertically in that case?

Comment: This is a great demonstration of the issue.  And it also resolves it to some degree.  It is very difficult to read the plot if you have many points e.g. 100-200 data points.  Is there anyway to add horizontal scrolling to this?

Comment: @Floris I updated the time scale. As for overlapping labels, I don't know an easy solution. A solution like this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486 helps to rotate them by 90 degrees. Which helps in some situations.

Comment: Terrific. I can see no reason why this should not be accepted as the correct solution - I think this solves the stated problem very well.

Comment: The above combined with the following: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7073-advanced-scroll-plot-with-subplot-handling will allow you to work with N points.  Good stuff.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for that link! Now the answer is complete.